# IntelliJ java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger

Tags: java, intellij-idea, classpath

I am using Intellij Idea for my project. I create a new maven project and I imported  a Java (not maven) project in intellij. The Java project contains some jars and I added the Java project to my new project.

But I have this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
>       at asvgeo.common.FileUtils.<clinit>(FileUtils.java:106) ~[bin/:na]

Can anyone help me?